# python scapy module gives error 19 no device even for valid port

Tags: python, scapy

My sincere apologies, that even after I googled and scanned the stackoverflow archive for my answer.. but even after trying few work-around I am still hitting the same issue..

I have a ubuntu host. On which I am invoking my python script. As a part of that script, it will login into another remote ubuntu host(scapy 2.2.0 is running) and run my scapy function to generate unicast pkt on a well-known port

Here is the scapy function:

```
def send_scapy(self,port='vintf10',num_frames=10,scale_macs=0):
    '''
    Generates L2 frames(incl Payload) with both Src & Dest MAC == Unicast
    num_frames for each SRC-MAC is sent out. Returns a list of SRC_MAC generated for further verifying in Flow & L2 Tables of VEM
    '''
    src_mac_list = []
    for i in range(num_frames):
              oui = [ 0x00, 0x11, 0x22,
              random.randint(0x00, 0x7f),
              random.randint(0x00, 0xff),
              random.randint(0x00, 0xff) ]
              src_mac = ':'.join(map(lambda x: "%02x" % x, oui))
              src_mac_list.append(src_mac)
    try:
           payload = 'REMOTE REMOTE REMOTE REMOTE REMOTE'
           brcd_log.info ("Payload of the to-be-generated frames = \n%s" % payload)
           brcd_log.info (" SRC MAC LIST  == %s" % src_mac_list)
           for i in range(len(src_mac_list)):
              print "MAC == %s" % src_mac_list[i]
              #sendp(Ether(dst='00:16:17:18:19:20',src=src_mac_list[i])/IP()/payload,iface=port,count = 1)
              pkt = Ether(dst='00:16:17:18:19:20',src=src_mac_list[i])/IP()
              print "PKT == %s" % pkt
              sendp(pkt,iface=port,count = 1)
              brcd_log.info ("Sent Out of Port %s ,1 frame with Unicast Src MAC %s and Unicast Dest MAC 00:16:17:18:19:20" %(port,src_mac_list[i]))


when I run on calling this function as below, the following error comes:
self.remote_kvm = Kvm_Infra(self.vem_2_ip,self.vem2_uname,self.vem2_pwd)
self.remote_kvm.send_scapy() ##

Error:
root@com-node12-36:/home/localadmin# 2014-04-07 22:47:57,520 [INFO] brcd_os - Payload of the to-be-generated frames =
REMOTE REMOTE REMOTE REMOTE REMOTE
2014-04-07 22:47:57,524 [INFO] brcd_os -  SRC MAC LIST  == ['00:11:22:23:bb:88', '00:11:22:5a:e6:b8', '00:11:22:13:70:39', '00:11:22:42:b6:11', '00:11:22:16:a4:ff', '00:11:22:1c:23:88', '00:11:22:3a:3b:b6', '00:11:22:3e:dd:f0', '00:11:22:03:5b:72', '00:11:22:7b:16:d7']
MAC == 00:11:22:23:bb:88
PKT ==  "#»E@
2014-04-07 22:47:57,531 [INFO] brcd_os - Exception Type = <class 'socket.error'>, Exception Object = [Errno 19] No such device
```

<<<<<<<<<<<

what am i blatantly missing here ?

When I call the same function in the local host(host from where the python script is invoked), then it works fine. Moreover in the remote host, when I manually try the same steps(what the function is doing for the same valid port), it works

Comment: Can redo the copy and paste of that error - and apply the code formatting option to it? The `{}` button.

Comment: @RyPeck: This is the error brcd_os - Exception Type = <class 'socket.error'>, Exception Object = [Errno 19] No such device

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that while communicating with the remote host, the transferred values are converted to `unicode`. This could happen if, for example, the format used to transfer the IP address is `json`. Then, although the printed values show nothing special and even when comparing to the expected `str` values, everything seems fine, in reality perhaps the underlying infrastructure doesn't handle `unicode` well. Try printing the types of all transferred values and converting them back to `str`.